# Scala specs2 matchers with "aka"

Tags: scala, specs2

I would like to check if a string contains another while providing a label using "aka". For instance:

```
"31 west 23rd street, NY" aka "address"  must contain("11065")
```

This fails with

```
address '31 west 23rd street, NY' doesn't contain '11065'.
```

However, I would like to specify that 11066 is a zip code. I.e.:

```
"31 west 23rd street, NY" aka "address"  must contain("11065") aka "zip code"
```

Which doesn't work.

Any idea how to achieve that?
The required result I expect is:

```
address '31 west 23rd street, NY' doesn't contain zip code '11065'.
```

Below is a possible solution, but I dislike it since it's not spec2 native and only supports strings:

```
def contain(needle: String, aka: String) = new Matcher[String] {
  def apply[S <: String](b: Expectable[S]) = {
    result(needle != null && b.value != null && b.value.contains(needle),
      s"${b.description} contains $aka '$needle'",
      s"${b.description} doesn't contain $aka '$needle'", b)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution applicable to all matchers. In this case you can reuse the `aka` machinery

```
def contain(expected: Expectable[String]): Matcher[String] = new Matcher[String] {
  def apply[S <: String](e: Expectable[S]): MatchResult[S] =
    result(e.value.contains(expected.value),
      s" ${e.value} contains ${expected.description} ${expected.value}",
      s" ${e.value} does not contain ${expected.description}",
      e)
}

"31 west 23rd street, NY" aka "address"  must contain("11065" aka "the zip code")
```

This displays

```
 31 west 23rd street, NY does not contain the zip code '11065'
```

Comment: This solution is slightly better than mine since it uses the original aka method. I modified the 5th line a little to fit my requirement: s"${e.description} does not contain ${expected.description}",